# Junit extend test case to test child

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I have class and test case `FormTest` which tests `Form`

```
public class Form {
   public doSomething() {} 
}

public class GreenForm extends Form  {
   @Override
   public doSomething() {}
}

public class YellowForm  extends Form {
}

public class FormTest {
   Form form = new Form();

   @Test
   public void doSomethingTest() { getForm().doSomething() }

   public Form getForm() { return form; }
}
```

**Is extending `FormTest` is propper way to test `GreenForm` and overriden method?** Ex:

```
public class GreenFormTest extends FormTest  {
   Form form = new GreenForm();

   @Override
   public Form getForm() { return form; }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have some trouble with the inheritance syntax. `GreenForm` overrides a method of Form without extending it and `GreenFormTest` is missing the name of it's parent class.

Comment: @DanielLerps thank you for pointing out, I hope this small syntax mistakes didn't confuse you about my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your notion of how to test this and do this regularly. The pattern I follow is this:

```
public class FormTest{
    private Form form;

    @Before 
    public void setup(){
        // any other needed setup
        form = getForm();
        // any other needed setup
    }

    protected Form getForm(){
        return new Form();
    }

    @Test
    // do tests of Form class
}

public class GreenTest{
    private GreenForm form;

    @Before 
    public void setup(){
        form = getForm();
        // any other needed setup
        super.setup();
        // any other needed setup
    }

    @Override
    protected Form getForm(){
        return new GreenForm();
    }

    @Test
    // do tests of how GreenForm is different from Form
    // you might also need to override specific tests if behavior of the method
    // under test is different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setUp`() method of TestCase for that.

```
public class Form
{
    public void doSomething(){}
}

public class GreenForm extends Form
{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){}
}
```

With the tests:

```
public class FormTest extends TestCase
{
    protected Form f;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        f = new Form();
    }

    @Test
    public void testForm()
    {
        // do something with f
    }
}

public class GreenFormTest extends FormTest
{
    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp()
    {
        f = new GreenForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method precludes the ability of `FormTest` to do anything in the `@Before`

Comment: You can call `super.setUp()` to execute everything you want `FormTest` to do. You just specify any changes in the `setUp()` of the child class after the super call.

Comment: True, however having `protected` fields is bad practice. I have made a suggestion that this very similar to this but using the form I usually take.

Comment: I see your point. But if the child class has additional methods that need testing you permit them to be called if you hide the attributes. Let's say `GreenForm` has a method `doSomethingElse()` that also needs to be tested. In order to get access to `f` in `GreenFormTest` it either needs to be protected or needs a getter-method (which gets difficult if you have multiple test objects).

Comment: Actually I would suggest that `GreenFormTest` would have it's own reference of type `GreenForm` instead to trying to use `FormTest's` `Form` reference that would probably have to be constantly cast. Check out my answer to see what I mean.